# How to display number of rows from table in Navigation Drawer Counter?

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I am new in Android Development, Is there a way on how I can display the number of Rows from my table in the counter? I found the code below from a tutorial made by androidhive. I tried creating a function that will get count the number of data from my table but I don't know how to insert it in the code below. Thanks in advance.

```
// Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3,       -1), true, "22"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3,       -1), true, "22"));
```

in this line **true** means you want to show counter and **22** means count 
now your requirement is number of rows from table first calclulate your number of rows from table through **cursor** (if your using sqlite database locally then) else you will get that count from webservice (if your using remote database)

after that pass that count variable to

```
 navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3,       -1), true, count));
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. By the way, I found a code and I was wondering what the syntax is to insert the result in the counter. Or is it even possible?                                              int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sections", null);

Comment: here your number of rows your getting is in integer format and if you see androidhive data type for count it is string so you need to convert your integer count into string like simple way is numRows+""